# Casting to base class without knowing name of class in C#

Tags: c#, oop, casting, visitor-pattern

I've been implementing visitor pattern in C#. What I have is:

Hierarchy of classes:

```
public class A {
  public virtual void Accept(Visitor visitor)
  {
    visitor.Visit(this);
  }
}

public class B : A {
  public override void Accept(Visitor visitor)
  {
    visitor.Visit(this);
  }
}
```

The `Visitor` class:

```
public abstract class Visitor {
  public virtual void Visit(A item) {
    //...
  }
  public virtual void Visit(B item) {
    Visit(item as A);
  }
}
```

Concrete `Visitor` class:

```
public class ConcreteVisitor : Visitor {
  public override void Visit(B item) {
    // do something
    // and call Visit for base class
    Visit(item as A); // I need to know type A.
  }
}
```

Is there any way to call `Visit` for `item`'s base class without knowing its direct base class name? I would like to be able to change hierarchy without changing `ConcreteVisitor` class.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you even have `void Visit(B item)` if the only thing it will does is call `void Visit(A item)`

Comment: Just call base.Visit(item) but the fact you need that it may be that signal that something else is wrong in your design.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I don't want to call Visit in base Visitor, but Visit for base class of item, something like `Visit(item.AsBaseClass())`

Comment: Isn't it what base class does? It's _strange_ to do something like that (but you code is a fictional example then I can't see your reasons) however if you really need it then at least do it in one place only (the base class). Note that base class (Visitor) is abstract then why do you have any logic in Visit(B) method if you do not wish to call it?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I need this because of reasons not included in the snippet ;) I didn't include them trying to be as concise as I could. In short words: Hierarchy makes a tree and I need to be able to traverse this tree. Default action for Visit(A) is go into children recursively - foreach(A child in GetChildren()) { child.Accept(this) }. If there was no Visit(B) method I couldn't override it in OtherConcreteVisitor and there would be no way for writing specific action for visiting B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it the responsibility of `A`. With a method for example:

```
public class A {
  public virtual void Accept(Visitor visitor)
  {
    visitor.Visit(this);
  }
  public A AsBase() 
  {
     return this;
  }
}
```

and

```
public class ConcreteVisitor : Visitor {
  public override void Visit(B item) {
    // do something
    // and call Visit for base class
    Visit(item.AsBase()); // convert to base type
  }
}
```

PS: your design is maybe a bit odd, but I was challenged by your question ;)

Answer (score 0):

I really believe that there's a simpler solution which involves changing visitor's method identifiers:

```
public class ConcreteVisitor : Visitor {
  public override void VisitB(B item) {
    VisitA(item);
  }
}
```

As `B` is `A`, the upcast is **implicit**.

For example, a real case might be:

```
public abstract class CarVisitor 
{
     public virtual Engine VisitEngine(Engine engine) => engine;

     public virtual DieselEngine VisitDieselEngine(DieselEngine engine) => engine;
}

public sealed class MyCarVisitor : CarVisitor
{
     public override DieselEngine VisitDieselEngine(DieselEngine engine)
     {
          VisitEngine(engine);

          return engine;
     }
}
```